# DROP Table command returns Error

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-synapse

I am using the following command in Azure SQL DatawareHouse to Drop the Table

`EXEC('DROP TABLE dbo.ext123');` 
Table name will be updated dynamically hence EXEC statement to drop them.

But i get the Following Error.

```
Cannot drop the table 'dbo.ext123', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I can see the Table exists via SSMS, and can drop it using SSMS.

But not able to drop when running it via Script even within SSMS.

What could i be missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the 'ext123' table name, I'm assuming this is an EXTERNAL table. If so, the syntax is a bit different.

For a *normal table*:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.ext123;
```

For an *external table*:

```
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.ext123;
```

See the [DROP EXTERNAL TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-external-table-transact-sql) topic for details.